# DDoS attacks targeting Android

Tags: android, ddos

I am currently studying some Android topics and I've been having difficulties finding answers regarding DDoS attacks.

My question is:
Are Android devices vulnerable to DDoS attacks or does Android provide some kind of protection for this?

I understand that there is very little gain in doing such attacks, but I just want to know if it is possible.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you explained what you know about DDoS. I'm not sure that any single device could have protection against DDoS.

Comment: And also tell do you talk about voice service or data service

Comment: Are you talking about receiving DDoS attacks ... or initiating them?

Comment: Pretty much everything with an internet connection is vulnerable to DDoS attacks against that connection.

Comment: Wifi, 3g?, 4g? It depends how it's performed. Android wifi would be as susceptible to DOS attacks as any other network interface without some intrusion detection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android devices are vulnerable to DDOS attacks. The Android Operating system does not contain any special protection against DDOS attacks. (However, DDOS attacks are typically aimed at web servers with the intent of preventing legit users from accessing them and Android OS is not used as a web server, so you are unlikely to find a DDOS against it)

In general, DDOS attacks cannot be blocked by the targeted device. DDOS protection for a website or network tends to be in the form a robust network to handle the increased burden of the attack while maintaining normal functions.